# Migration in .Net 6.0 project to create database

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I add migration to my .Net 6.0 project and when I run command "update-database", the database is created but when I don't run this command and run my project, it doesn't create the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Database.Migrate  in your application database context, to run command "update-database" programmatically.

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext {
    public MyContext() {
        Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Run sync migrations in constructor every time context created? - Not a good idea. I would prefer to call it only once near entry point of your application.

Comment: if you don't want to run it every time, just check whether there is a pending migration
if (Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count() > 0)
            {
                Database.Migrate();
            }

Answer (score 1):

> and run my project, it doesn't create the database

You should run it programmatically, something like this:

```
using (var context = new MyContext(options))
{
  await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
}
```

If there was no any pending migrations, this code does kinda nothing.
For instance, if you had the only migration for creation db and some initial tables, db will not be recreated.
List of applied migrations you can see in special table called `_MigrationsHistory`.

You can run also this one (but no migrations are applied):

```
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

That's all. Hope it will help.